# Draw circle without fill color in cocos2d?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing an app based on Nucleus, Orbit and electron animation. I did circle drawing using this code

```
CCDrawNode *_circleNode = [CCDrawNode node];

[_circleNode drawDot: ccp(100, 100) radius: 60.f color: [CCColor redColor]];

[self addChild:_circleNode];
```

But I need to draw three orbit path in circle shape without filled color. how can i achieve this kind of work in cocos2d. for Reference image given below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CCDrawNode uses shader to draw the dot, think in case of just drawing stroke it makes more sense to construct the path from triangles. 
Fastest should be create new node class

```
// inside MyCustomNodeClass node class
#import "CCDrawingPrimitives.h" 

- (void)draw {
  ccDrawCircle(ccp(100, 100), 60, 360, 64, NO); 
}
```

Then you can do :

```
_circleNode = [[MyCustomNodeClass alloc] init];
[self addChild:_circleNode];
```

You can later improve the custom class to use the VAO instead of ccDrawCircle.

Comment: i am getting error like this  Implicit declaration of function 'ccDrawCircle' is invalid in C99 and also Apple linker error in my custom class

Comment: It's declared in the CCDrawingPrimitives.h

Comment: I tried this but #import "CCDrawingPrimitives.h" file not found. i am using cocos2d v3.0

Comment: Hmm in v3.0 there should be this class still:
https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-swift/blob/v3.0/cocos2d/CCDrawingPrimitives.m

Comment: whether i need to add this class into framework? or what can i do to fix this problem

Comment: sorry i am using #define COCOS2D_VERSION 0x00030100
#define COCOS2D_BUILD @"beta"

Comment: Yeah i guess you can just try to manually add that class to your project might work nicely. Did not tried latest cocos2d, but looks like drawing primitives has been removed. Still using properly generated VAO buffer is the proper solution to the problem.